# Create a sliding window of data index positions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write a function that returns the index positions of a sliding window over a Pandas DataFrame as a list of (train, test) tuples.

Example:

```
df.head(10)

   col_a   col_b
0  20.1    6.0
1  19.1    7.1
2  19.1    8.9
3  16.5    11.0
4  16.0    11.1
5  17.4    8.7  
6  19.3    9.7
7  22.8    12.6
8  21.4    11.9
9  23.0    12.8

def split_function(df, train_length, test_length):
  some_logic_to_split_dataframe
  split_indices = [(train_idx, test_idx) for index_tuples in split_dataframe_logic]
  return split_indices
```

Desired outcome:

```
train_length = 2
test_length = 1

split_indices = split_function(df, train_length, test_length)
split_indices

output:

[((0,1), (2)), ((1,2),(3)),...,((7,8), (9)) etc]
```

The function loop/generator expression would need to terminate when the test_index == last observation too.

All help very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `rolling` method offered by `pandas`.

```py
split_indices = []
def split(x):
    split_indices.append((x.index[:train_length], x.index[-test_length:]))
    return np.nan

df['col1'].rolling(train_length + test_length).apply(split)
```

This code will create the following `split_indices`

```py
>>> split_indices
[(Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([4, 5], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([7], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([6, 7], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')),
 (Int64Index([7, 8], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([9], dtype='int64'))]
```

After you can easily get the data of your dataframe of a given index

```py
>>> df.loc[split_indices[3][0]]
    col1    col2
3  16.5    11.0
4  16.0    11.1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. This is nearly the solution I believe, however I need to pass a dataframe to the function, and the function would return the indices of the split? I am not looking to add this as a column.